# Android application can have multiple launcher activities?

Tags: android

Android application can have multiple launcher activities? Where to give conditions on which, which activity to launch?

Comment: Please follow this link https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2012/06/04/create-application-with-multiple-entry-point-activities/

Comment: Please paste your menifests file code, i have understood your actual problem

Answer (score 0):

By specifying intent action as launcher in your manifest, you can have more than one launcher activities of your application

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Add this in your activities

Comment: Will it work? How OS will decide which of the launcher activity to trigger?

Comment: @NarendraJi system will decide from category.DEFAULT <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>